# Previous value remain stored in next iteration in do while loop

Tags: c, string, do-while

In this program of converting number to word. I have used do while loop to restart(continue) the program again.
But it's creating problem. 1st time program gets successfully run but when condition satisfy in *while* and program gets continue then it prints new value along with previous value.
similar condition in every next iteration. Previous value remain stored and get printed with new one every time.
what may the error? I am unable to find that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int n, i, r, p; /*r for remainder. i for increment. n for ruppes in number taken from user.*/
    char str1[100]={0}, str2[100]={0}, str3[100]={0}, str4[100]={0}, str5[100]={0}, str6[100]={0}, str7[100]={0}, str8[100]={0}, str9[100]={0}, cont;
    do
    {
        clrscr();
        printf("\nvalid till 99 crore 99 lakhs 99 thousand 9 hundred 99");
        printf("\n\nwrite your ruppes in integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        p = n;
        if (n == 0)
            printf("\nYou don't have any ruppe.");

        i = 0;
        while (n > 0)
        {
            r = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            if (i == 0 && n % 10 != 1)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str1, "one");
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str1, "two");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str1, "three");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str1, "four");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str1, "five");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str1, "six");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str1, "seven");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str1, "eight");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str1, "nine");
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                {
                    if (p % 10 == 0)
                        strcpy(str2, "ten");
                    else if (p % 10 == 1)
                        strcpy(str2, "eleven");
                    else if (p % 10 == 2)
                        strcpy(str2, "twelve");
                    else if (p % 10 == 3)
                        strcpy(str2, "thirteen");
                    else if (p % 10 == 4)
                        strcpy(str2, "fourteen");
                    else if (p % 10 == 5)
                        strcpy(str2, "fifteen");
                    else if (p % 10 == 6)
                        strcpy(str2, "sixteen");
                    else if (p % 10 == 7)
                        strcpy(str2, "seventeen");
                    else if (p % 10 == 8)
                        strcpy(str2, "eighteen");
                    else if (p % 10 == 9)
                        strcpy(str2, "nineteen");
                }
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str2, "twenty ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str2, "thirty ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str2, "fourty ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str2, "fifty ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str2, "sixty ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str2, "seventy ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str2, "eighty ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str2, "ninty ");
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str3, "one hundred ");
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str3, "two hundred ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str3, "three hundred ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str3, "four hundred ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str3, "five hundred ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str3, "six hundred ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str3, "seven hundred ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str3, "eight hundred ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str3, "nine hundred ");
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                if (r == 0)
                    strcpy(str4, "thousand ");
                else if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str4, "one thousand ");
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str4, "two thousand ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str4, "three thousand ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str4, "four thousand ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str4, "five thousand ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str4, "six thousand ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str4, "seven thousand ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str4, "eight thousand ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str4, "nine thousand ");
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str5, "ten ");

                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str5, "twenty ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str5, "thirty ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str5, "fourty ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str5, "fifty ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str5, "sixty ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str5, "seventy ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str5, "eighty ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str5, "ninty ");
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                if (r == 0)
                    strcpy(str6, "lakh ");
                else if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str6, "one lakh ");
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str6, "two lakh ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str6, "three lakh ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str6, "four lakh ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str6, "five lakh ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str6, "six lakh ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str6, "seven lakh ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str6, "eight lakh ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str6, "nine lakh ");
            }
            if (i == 6)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str7, "ten ");

                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str7, "twenty ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str7, "thirty ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str7, "fourty ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str7, "fifty ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str7, "sixty ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str7, "seventy ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str7, "eighty ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str7, "ninty ");
            }
            if (i == 7)
            {
                if (r == 0)
                    strcpy(str8, "crore ");
                else if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str8, "one crore ");
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str8, "two crore ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str8, "three crore ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str8, "four crore ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str8, "five crore ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str8, "six crore ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str8, "seven crore ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str8, "eight crore ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str8, "nine crore ");
            }

            if (i == 8)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str9, "ten ");

                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str9, "twenty ");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str9, "thirty ");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str9, "fourty ");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str9, "fifty ");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str9, "sixty ");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str9, "seventy ");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str9, "eighty ");
                if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str9, "ninty ");
            }

            i++;
        }
        if (str9[0] != '\0')
        {
            strcat(str9, str8);
            strcat(str9, str7);
            strcat(str9, str6);
            strcat(str9, str5);
            strcat(str9, str4);
            strcat(str9, str3);
            strcat(str9, str2);
            strcat(str9, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str9);
        }
        else if (str9[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str8, str7);
            strcat(str8, str6);
            strcat(str8, str5);
            strcat(str8, str4);
            strcat(str8, str3);
            strcat(str8, str2);
            strcat(str8, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str8);
        }

        else if (str8[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str7, str6);
            strcat(str7, str5);
            strcat(str7, str4);
            strcat(str7, str3);
            strcat(str7, str2);
            strcat(str7, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str7);
        }

        else if (str7[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str6, str5);
            strcat(str6, str4);
            strcat(str6, str3);
            strcat(str6, str2);
            strcat(str6, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str6);
        }

        else if (str6[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str5, str4);
            strcat(str5, str3);
            strcat(str5, str2);
            strcat(str5, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str5);
        }
        else if (str5[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str4, str3);
            strcat(str4, str2);
            strcat(str4, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str4);
        }
        else if (str4[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str3, str2);
            strcat(str3, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str3);
        }
        else if (str3[0] == '\0')
        {
            strcat(str2, str1);
            printf("\n\n%s", str2);
        }
        else
            printf("\n\n%s", str1);

        printf("\n\n press y or j for continue or any other key to exit:  ");
        scanf(" %c", &cont);

    } while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'j');
    printf("\nThanking You");
    return 0;
}
```

Below are the output after compilation of codes

```
valid till 99 crore 99 lakhs 99 thousand 9 hundred 99

write your ruppes in integer: 121


one hundred twenty one

 press y or j for continue or any other key to exit:  y

valid till 99 crore 99 lakhs 99 thousand 9 hundred 99

write your ruppes in integer: 456


one hundred twenty onefour hundred fifty six

 press y or j for continue or any other key to exit:
```

Here during 1st time program gives correct result. But in next iteration it give correct result but result get printed along result of previous iteration. Means on every next iteration in do while loop, previous value remain strored.

Please see below a small program based on the concept of above program. It's make easy to understand the concept of above program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//program to convert entered number to word from 21 to 99
int main()
{
    char str1[30] = {0}, str2[30] = {0}, c;
    int n, i, r;
    do
    {
        printf("write the value of integer within 21 to 99: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
        {
            r = n % 10; //for remainder
            n = n / 10;

            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (r == 1)
                    strcpy(str1, " one");
                else if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str1, " two");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str1, " three");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str1, " four");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str1, " five");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str1, " six");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str1, " seven");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str1, " eight");
                else if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str1, " nine");
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                if (r == 2)
                    strcpy(str2, "twenty");
                else if (r == 3)
                    strcpy(str2, "thirty");
                else if (r == 4)
                    strcpy(str2, "fourty");
                else if (r == 5)
                    strcpy(str2, "fifty");
                else if (r == 6)
                    strcpy(str2, "sixty");
                else if (r == 7)
                    strcpy(str2, "seventy");
                else if (r == 8)
                    strcpy(str2, "eighty");
                else if (r == 9)
                    strcpy(str2, "ninty");
            }
        }
        strcat(str2, str1);
        printf("\n%s", str2);

        printf("\nwrite y to continue or any other key to exit: ");
        scanf(" %c", &c);
    } while (c == 'y');
    printf("\nThanking You");
    return 0;
}
```

Above program works without any issue. Only problem with 1st asked program. Sorry for this concept, I don't know any other concept to solve this problem. You can suggest me.

Comment: Don't describe the code, show the code.  Describing code is saying "this is basically what I'm telling the computer to do".  Problem is, computers don't do *basically* what you tell them, they do **exactly** what you tell them.  So tell us **exactly** what you're telling the computer to do, i.e. show your code.

Comment: @dbush sir, I have added the code

Comment: Please give us: 1) The input 2) the expected output 3) the actual output

Comment: @4386427 sir, I have updated everything  with output and error shown. Please see it again

Answer (score 1):

Here is at least one bug:

All your strings are uninitialized the first time you run the loop. So when you do `if (str9[0] != '\0')` it's likely that you access an uninitialized value which is real bad.

Further, the second time you run the loop all the strings have the value from the first time. That will give strange results.

To be honest I don't understand the logic of your program but to fix the string problem change:

```
char str1[100], str2[100], str3[100], str4[100], str5[100], str6[100], str7[100], str8[100], str9[100], cont;
do
{
```

to

```
char cont;
do
{
    char str1[100] = {0};
    char str2[100] = {0};
    ...
    char str9[100] = {0};
```

Also this part seems strange:

```
        n = n / 10;
        if (i == 0 && n % 10 != 1)
```

Sure you want to change `n` before the test `n % 10 != 1` ? It seems wrong.

Comment: I have updated program with your concept to initilize the string. But further problem is same. Please read  again the program. I have added output as well as error. Sorry for disturbing again.